# Why does the_content filter output var_dump, print_r or echo surrounded by quotes?

Tags: the-content

I'd like to alter the images for a particular page using `the_content` filter. When debugging or testing elements of the code, I've noticed that the output is surrounded by quotes.

For example, `print_r( $images )`  from `preg_match_all( '/<img[^>]+>/i', $content, $images );` produces:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=&gt;
  array(1) {
    [0]=&gt;
    string(143) "<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/someimage.jpeg" alt="" class="wp-image-566" width="300" height="150">"
  }
}
```

The string is wrapped with `"`

- Why is this happening?

Comment: can you post a code example with some context of the debugging you are doing that produces this?